# Pulling all the data in SQL database and then filter it using LINQ

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq, caching, c#-4.0

I have a list of user permissions. I'm thinking of pulling all the data from the `UserPermission` table, put it in cache and then filter it by `userID` using LINQ.

So the next time somebody tries to access the User Permission Screen, I'll have the data in cache and just filter and display the necessary base on the userID.

Is there any performance in doing it? Or still faster to filter it in the database/data layer?

Comment: What Database type? How many users? How often do they access that screen? I think usually it's faster to let the DB do the filtering opposed to optimistically cache *everything* in the DB

Comment: Put the logic of the filtering in a class and make it as simpler as possible (I think going though the database will be the one). Then, if you do some performance testing or because of the actual use of the application you see the performance is not good, start thinking on optimizing. http://alturl.com/b3dt2

Comment: well, I was thinking of using it in almost all my module not in particular UserPermission only. I'll be using MS SQL 2008 and ASP.NET 4.0 C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 factors at play here

1. The speed of filtering the data via LINQ
2. The speed of filtering the data via SQL and returning that data from your data store to the application

Generally speaking, for small sets of data, the difference between 1. and 2. will be negligible.

For large sets of data with a small result, the 2. will have better performance

For large sets of data with a large result, the 1. will have better performance

But of course this generalisation is totally useless as it all depends on your environment and your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to weigh up latency vs performance vs stale data.

It's always different for different use cases...

But this kind of thing is already built into .net - look up ASP.NET Authorization Providers